Can resistors having equal magnitudes of potential difference be considered to be in parallel?
More specifically, if potential difference across a resistor, is exactly negative of the potential difference across another resistor, can they be considered to be in parallel? If so, why?
Can the given resistor be considered as an internal resistance (as $\Delta V$ is negative)?
Let's say I have the following system:

Finding points of equal potential difference:

$\Delta V$ across $R_1$ is $V_{a}-V_{b}$.
$\Delta V$ across $R_2$ is $V_{b}-V_{a}$
$\Delta V$ across $R_3$ is $V_{a}-V_{b}$
I knew that $R_1$ and $R_3$ would certainly be in parallel with each other, but would $R_3$ be in parallel with them as well?
I figured since $R_2$ had the same magnitude of potential difference $|V_{a}-V_{b}|$ as the battery, it could be an internal resistance (as current flows from negative terminal to positive terminal inside the battery).
With these assumptions, I got equivalent resistance as $\dfrac{3R}{2}$, however, on applying Kirchoff's Law, we get the equivalent resistance as $\dfrac{R}{3}$ implying all 3 resistances are in parallel.
Why is it so, despite $R_{2}$ not having the same potential difference as $R_{1}$ and $R_{3}$?

I believe your voltage difference calculation for R2 is backwards. Remember that current does not necessarily flow left-to-right for all resistors, but rather, from high to low potential. If we assume Va is higher, than current will flow from right to left across R2 on your diagram. Redrawing the diagram may also help to visualize what is really going on. But indeed, the three resistors are in parallel.

All three resistors have one end connected to A and the other to B, so they are all in parallel.
